# SQL: Ordering a UNION selection and displaying a ('string + count') if null

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have quite a complex query here (for me at least):

```
SELECT h.name,  IFNULL(tip.type, 'positive') type,
CONCAT('Total ', tip.type, 's available = ', COUNT(tip.type)) total

FROM racing.race r, racing.horse h 
    LEFT JOIN racing.horse_race_details hrd ON hrd.horse_id = h.horse_id 
    LEFT JOIN racing.proform_tip tip ON h.horse_id = tip.horse_id AND tip.race_id = hrd.race_id
WHERE r.race_id = hrd.race_id AND r.race_id = 123456
GROUP BY h.name, tip.type

UNION 

SELECT h.name, IFNULL(tip.type, 'negative') type,
CONCAT('Total ', tip.type, 's available = ', COUNT(tip.type)) total

FROM racing.race r, racing.horse h 
    LEFT JOIN racing.horse_race_details hrd ON hrd.horse_id = h.horse_id 
    LEFT JOIN racing.proform_tip tip ON h.horse_id = tip.horse_id AND tip.race_id = hrd.race_id
WHERE r.race_id = hrd.race_id AND r.race_id = 123456
GROUP BY h.name, tip.type ;
```

Which creates a selection like this:

[image: current query result]

However, I need to do 2 more things with this:

1. order this by h.name (just adding ORDER BY causes it to break)
2. display the string 'Total negatives available = 0' if it's NULL

Comment: You only ever have one `ORDER BY` clause. It goes after the last `SELECT` in the union and applies to all unioned clauses. I noticed that you said "ORDER BY clauses" (plural)

Comment: Do you really want the duplicates for "Double Speak"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two queries are identical except for the `select` clause.  That would normally mean that the `union` is unnecessary.

Second, you are combining explicit and implicit joins.  As a rule, simply do not use commas in the `from` clause.

I think the following is the query you want:

```
SELECT h.name, COALESCE(tip.type, 'negative') as type,
       CONCAT('Total ', COALESCE(tip.type, 'negative'), 's available = ', COUNT(tip.type)) total
FROM racing.race r LEFT JOIN
     racing.horse_race_details hrd
     ON r.race_id = hrd.race_id LEFT JOIN
     racing.horse h 
     ON hrd.horse_id = h.horse_id LEFT JOIN
     racing.proform_tip tip
     ON h.horse_id = tip.horse_id AND tip.race_id = hrd.race_id
WHERE r.race_id = 123456
GROUP BY h.name, tip.type
ORDER BY h.name;
```

This assumes that the missing `tip.type` is treated as `'negative'`.

EDIT:

If you *really* want both positive and negative in the case of missing tips, then you can use `union`:

```
SELECT h.name, 'negative' as type,
       CONCAT('Total ', 'negative', 's available = ', COUNT(tip.type)) total
FROM racing.race r LEFT JOIN
     racing.horse_race_details hrd
     ON r.race_id = hrd.race_id LEFT JOIN
     racing.horse h 
     ON hrd.horse_id = h.horse_id LEFT JOIN
     racing.proform_tip tip
     ON h.horse_id = tip.horse_id AND tip.race_id = hrd.race_id
WHERE r.race_id = 123456 AND (tip.type IS NULL or tip.type = 'negative')
GROUP BY h.name
UNION ALL
SELECT h.name, 'positive' as type,
       CONCAT('Total ', 'positive', 's available = ', COUNT(tip.type)) total
FROM racing.race r LEFT JOIN
     racing.horse_race_details hrd
     ON r.race_id = hrd.race_id LEFT JOIN
     racing.horse h 
     ON hrd.horse_id = h.horse_id LEFT JOIN
     racing.proform_tip tip
     ON h.horse_id = tip.horse_id AND tip.race_id = hrd.race_id
WHERE r.race_id = 123456 AND (tip.type IS NULL or tip.type = 'positive')
GROUP BY h.name
ORDER BY name
```

Note that the `where` logic changes the `union` to a `union all`.  `union all` is more efficient because duplicates are not removed.  The final order by uses `name`, but not `h.name`, because the table alias is not known outside of each subquery.

EDIT II:

You can do this without a bit `union all`, just with a little one:

```
SELECT h.name, tips.type as type,
       CONCAT('Total ', tips.type, 's available = ', COUNT(tip.type)) total
FROM racing.race r LEFT JOIN
     racing.horse_race_details hrd
     ON r.race_id = hrd.race_id LEFT JOIN
     racing.horse h 
     ON hrd.horse_id = h.horse_id LEFT JOIN
     racing.proform_tip tip
     ON h.horse_id = tip.horse_id AND tip.race_id = hrd.race_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT 'negative' as type union all
      SELECT 'positive
     ) tips
     on tip.type = tips.type or tip.type is NULL
WHERE r.race_id = 123456
GROUP BY h.name, tips.type
ORDER BY h.name;
```

Comment: I need to display both 'Total positives available = 0' and 'Total negatives available = 0' if there is no matching tip

Comment: @MihkelMark . . . The second edit is probably the best query for what you want.

Comment: Oddly it refuses this and says `Unknown column 'hrd.race_id' in 'on clause'`, but I don't get why - it's in the same place as where I put it.

Comment: @MihkelMark . . . I rearranged the joins.  More reasons not to put commas in `from` clauses.

Comment: It’s close, but it still leaves out the 0 count if there is only one of either absent. If there’s 0 of both, it counts it like it should. Say there's 2 positives and no negatives per horse, it only shows the positives. If there's 0 of both, it properly shows 0 for both. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @MihkelMark . . . If you want both negatives and positives for all horses, change the last join to a `cross join` and remove the condition.